# In the graph theory, is a strongly connected component SCC form a DAG?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, strongly-connected-graph

I was trying to solve a problem to design an algorithm to determine whether a direct graph is semi-connected. Someone says it can be done by using topological sort every SCC in the graph. And SCC is guaranteed to be DAG. However, I think SCC graph must be a circle, why it is a DAG since DAG mean no circle.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the argument.

Suppose you have a graph that has points

`A1 <--> A2 <--> A3 --> B1 <--> B2 --> C1 <--> C2`

and `A1 A2 A3`, `B1 B2`, `C1, C2` are SCC.

Then you treat `A1 A2 A3` as a single point `A`. Any node connecting to one of `A1 A2 A3` is treated as connecting to `A`, Any node connected from one of `A1 A2 A3` is treated as connected from `A`. Same for merging points to `B`, `C`

So it became `A --> B --> C`. It is guaranteed that this is a DAG.